# Getting TLS Protocol Version in Web API on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using this code to print the TLS Version (e.g. Tls12) when running a WebAPI project locally.

```
var tlsHandshakeFeature = context.Features.Get<ITlsHandshakeFeature>();
Console.WriteLine(tlsHandshakeFeature.Protocol);
```

After deploying the project to an Azure Web App, I get a `NullReferenceException` when accessing the `Protocol` property.

How can I retrieve the TLS version used for the current request when running a Dotnet Core Web API project on Azure?

Of course, the Azure Application Gateway terminates SSL/TLS client connections, so there is no direct connection between client and the application. But the gateway passes meta data to the application and so I somewhat assume (optimistically) the APIs in .NET Core may support this environment.

Comment: Like this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/01/25/tls-on-azure-app-services/ ?

Comment: @Michael: No, my application is the server and not sending any requests.

Comment: if it is a webapp you can check that on the azure portal: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azuregov/how-to-configure-tls-versions-in-app-service-and-functions-apps-in-azure-government/

Comment: @Thomas: I can configure it, but not check it for a specific connection. And of course I want to check it automatically, not by browsing a web page.

Comment: I mean once it is configured, why do you want to check ? are you not trusting your cloud provider ? Also this applies for inbound connections.

Comment: @Thomas: Why we want to check it is really not important, but we need to do it to identify problems on clients in a complex update procedure, which includes the switch to TLS 1.2. The client is not capable of exposing this connection information. The cloud provider does not provide this information in the interface. Configuring a whole site is not live checking a single active connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the Termination of the TLS connection at the Azure Application Gateway, the available information at the application container is limited.

I examined the HTTP X-Headers and the TLS version has not been recorded. So the problem simply is the gateway does not report the needed information to the application.